# Upgrading Wagtail from 2.9.3 to 2.11 breaks wagtail admin icons

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I've checked everything...
After upgrading interface looks like this:
[image: 1]

Totally broken, but the only thing that is breaking everything is icons...

Neither CMD or DevTools doesn't seem to show any missing files...

I have already ran all of the commands `makemigrations`, `migrate` and `collectstatic --clear`.
Running `manage.py check` didn't show up any errors.
Checked(disabled/enabled) all of the apps, didn't work.
Checked `urls.py` on any misconfiguration with staticfiles, still nothing.
Compared my `base.py`, `dev.py` files with fresh install of 2.11, didn't see nothing that can cause overriding CSS or JS(I'm using Django Debug Toolbar, tryed disabling it, didn't work, same as everything). Help. Please.

And also on a fresh install there was no "SKIP TO MAIN CONTENT" button on top. I don’t know what that has to do with anything

- Wagtail 2.11
- Django 3.0.11
- Using Pipenv for virtual environment

Comment: Have you tried force-refreshing the page, or viewing in a different browser?

Comment: @gasman Yes! In firefox dev, firefox, opera. Everywhere the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn! Of course, after posting a question, I found an answer. When running `collectstatic` I've noticed that there was too many `Found another file with the destination path...` messages, but did not take this into account. Then I realized that somehow in my core app staticfiles folder were duplicates of Wagtail's core static files, so I installed Wagtail 2.11 for the millionth time, ran the server and nothing changed... Fortunately, I've guessed(thanks to @gasman) to clear cache and reload the window and IT WORKED!

**Conslusion:** Check for duplicated static files, mine were from the old version of Wagtail, but Wagtail is on latest, which caused this issue...